# Error with named route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Why this simple named route throw in error

```js
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}));
```

I've also tested with controller instead of callback but always the same, the error is:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

I'm testing the code with PHP 5.4.x, but I don't think it's PHP related, am I missing something?

Comment: You're acessing `http://localhost/` ?

Comment: I've configured a dedicated VirtuaHost `http://example.dev`

Comment: Just edited the answer. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This route:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}));
```

Will define this URL for you:

```
http://example.dev/
```

But to create a link to this route you'll have to

```
URL::route('dashboard');
```

If you need to access your dashboard via

```
http://example.dev/dashboard
```

You have to define

```
Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}));
```

Comment: I have to pay more attention to the documentation [http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) before posting this kind of question. Thanks for explanation.